# What's the different between the result of HashMap.entrySet() and LinkedHashMap.entrySet(),do they have the same performance？

Tags: java

I know the different between the hashmap(arrays + linked) and linkedhashMap(keep the order when you put in it);

**My question is do the entrySet and LinkedEntrySet has the same feature as HashMap and LinkedHashMap?**

```
 Map<String,Integer> hashmap= new HashMap<>();
 Map<String,Integer> linkedmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

 Set hashset = hashmap.entrySet();//EntrySet
 Set linkedset = linkedmap .entrySet();//LinkedEntrySet

// Here is my test code
@Test
public void mapTest(){
    Map<String,Integer> hashMap= new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Integer> linkedHashMap= new LinkedHashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("1",1);
    hashMap.put("3",3);
    hashMap.put("2",2);
    hashMap.put("5",5);
    hashMap.put("8",8);
    hashMap.put("6",6);
    hashMap.put("7",7);
    hashMap.put("4",4);

    linkedHashMap.put("1",1);
    linkedHashMap.put("3",3);
    linkedHashMap.put("2",2);
    linkedHashMap.put("5",5);
    linkedHashMap.put("8",8);
    linkedHashMap.put("6",6);
    linkedHashMap.put("7",7);
    linkedHashMap.put("4",4);//LinkedHashMapwill keep the order

    Set hashSet = hashMap.entrySet();
    Set linkedSet= linkedHashMap.entrySet();//the linkedSetwill keep the order too???
    for (Object o : hashSet ) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
    for (Object o : linkedSet) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just debug and check it yourself?

Comment: I debug it already.first map return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8          second return1,3,2,5,8,6,7,4.  which bother me is that the first should return random order,but return asc order

Comment: They are whatever the Javadoc says they are. You cannnot rely on anything more than that.

Comment: `set.getClass()` and `set1.getClass()` should tell you what's class

Comment: thx ~ I find the answer return EntrySet LinkedEntrySet

Comment: The ascending order is a coincidence arising from a combination of how `String.hashCode()` works and the capacity of your `HashMap`. Instead of one-digit numbers, you may for example try non-consecutive letters (for example `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` and `y`). They shouldn’t come in ascending order. Or two-digit numbers 18, 19, 20 and 21.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code (Java 8), in both cases `entrySet()` returns an instance of an inner class of the corresponding `Map` implementation :

For `LinkedHashMap` :

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new LinkedEntrySet()) : es;
}
```

For `HashMap` :

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}
```

As you can see, they don't use neither `LinkedHashSet` nor `HashSet`. They have specific `Set` implementations.

And the reason they use specific internal implementations it that these `Set`s are backed by the respective `Map`s, so they don't have storage of their own.

Comment: Isn't this implementation specific after all? The method signature says a reference to a `Set` is returned. Who cares what the actual runtime type of the referred object is? If that would matter, a subclass of `Set` was used for the return type instead. Every new version of Java may radically change the implementation of these methods.

Comment: @Matthias Well, the OP cared enough to ask a question about it.